# Как сделать выход из аккаунта firebase на экран входа с Фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Моя идея такова сделать выход из аккаунта firebase через фрагмент, т.е на иконку в navigation menu ( который снизу ), происходит выход из активного аккаунта и переход на активити входа. Я сделал вроде бы, но это работает не так как хотелось, т.е выход происходит после перехода на фрагмент и нужно опять нажать на иконку. А еще при нажатии на кнопку назад на смартфоне он открывает предыдущее активити которое было, как это убрать?
Код который в фрагменте:

```
View exit;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        exit = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.exit);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(ExitFragment.this.getParentFragment().getActivity(), MainActivityEntrance.class));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Скриншот navigation menu:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть базовое правило, кто владеет контролом (кнопкой в вашем случае), тот и обрабатывает его события. У вас же какой-то фрагмент лезет в UI, которое не его, используя еще не свой контекст (`ExitFragment.this.getParentFragment().getActivity()`) для запуска новой активити. Я вообще не понимаю как ЭТО может работать.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja т.е вы хотите сказать мне это писать в Активити который соединяет все фрагменты?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja не совсем понял насчет контекста, извиняюсь

Comment: Да, кому принадлежит меню, тот на него и реагирует. Возможно и перезапускать активити не придется. О контексте. У каждого фрагмента есть доступ к активити, которая его запустила. Зачем ему стучаться в родительский фрагмент и просить дать его активити?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Благодарю вас, я перенес все на фрагмент, все заработало как надо. Спасибо вам!